# use of till and for

Tags: prepositions

If someone knows he has to spend long time in a jungle ; which preposition fits best here:

> What will happen to you in the jungle for thousands of years?
>   What will happen to you in the jungle till thousands of years?

Comment: Are you sure, "thousands of years"?  If it were "three months" then the preposition "after" would fit.  Or "during the course of three months".

Comment: Let's make it 'three months' __ should there be 'till' or 'for' if we are talking about things may happen to him during three months?

Answer (score 1):

You had written in the comments that "three months" is acceptable instead of "thousands of years", so let's proceed with that.

> "What will happen to you in the jungle till three months?"

That is grammatically incorrect. You can not say "til" or "till" or "until" here.

> "What will happen to you in the jungle for three months?"

Not quite right.  The word "for" might work in a similar sentence like "What happened to him when he was in the jungle for three months?" or "What would happen to him if he were in the jungle for three months".

Here are some alternate suggestions:

> "What will happen to you in the jungle during the course of three months?"

"During" is probably a clear answer.

> "What will happen to you in the jungle after three months?

Even though "after" is not the same as "during", it carries with it a bit of an implication of "during". "After" isn't a bad choice.

Comment: Having read [using the future tense and then "for" doesn't go...]  a question has occurred to me: What if one wants to wait somewhere for two hours... i.e. I am waiting here for two hours. He will stay at that place until two hours are over. Here 'for' is a present-to-future situation. So, will this be a right sentence?

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqii , you are right. It's not about the future tense. "We will stay for two hours". That's the future and it's ok.  Yes, it's very interesting...  There is just something about this combination of words.  There are three things going on here:  1. the word "happen", which doesn't typically take a time period, although it could.  2. the fact this is a question, rather than a statement. and 3. the future tense.  Something about this combination makes "for" not sound exactly right.  It may not be a pure grammatical error though. just an awkward phrasing.